# Issue with building BST from sorted arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, methods, binary-search-tree

I have the following code, but it gives an error where i call my "sortedArrayToBST" method, how do i fix this?

```
 public static <E> BTree<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> L) {

     BTree<E> T = new BTree<E>();

     sortedArrayToBST(L,T);    <-----gives error here.


     return T;

} 




private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
BTree<E> sortedArrayToBST(ArrayList<E> l, BTree<E> t) {

        if(t.getRoot() == null) {
        t.setRoot(new BTreeNode<E>(l.get(0)));
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < l.size();  i++) {   


             E q = l.get(i);
             BTreeNode<E> p = t.getRoot();

        while(true)
        {    
         if(q.compareTo(p.getElement()) <= 0)
         {  

          if(p.getLeftChild() == null)
           {     
           p.setLeftChild(new BTreeNode<E>(q));
           break;                         
           }
          else
          p = p.getLeftChild();
         }
         else if(q.compareTo(p.getElement()) > 0)
         {
          if(p.getRightChild() == null)
           {      
           p.setRightChild(new BTreeNode<E>(q));
           break;                            
           }
          else
              p = p.getRightChild();          
         }   
        }
     }
    return t;
 }
```

I would like to keep this structure.I am using custom imports that contain getLeftChild() and so on which should be pretty easy to understand.

Also if there is anyway to make this complete in linear time, that would be great. I am pretty sure its not as effective as O(n).

Comment: could you provide please more information about error you are getting

Comment: "The method sortedArrayToBST(ArrayList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> , BTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> in the type program is not applicable for arguments (ArrayList<E> , BTree<E> )" and this is given by eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`E` can be anything in `taulukostaPuu`, it is not constrained. However, in `sortedArrayToBST` it must extend `Comparable`. So you get a type conflict.

Use the same constraints here:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>>
    BTree<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> L)
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix it?